# Set message along with response.status in bottle (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, bottle, http-status-codes

How can I replace the default message by one of my own in bottle (Python 3.5).

Like so:

```
response.status = 400
response.message = "Something went bad" # replace the default "Bad request"
```

Is it possible? Had a look in the docs but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bottle.HTTPResponse()`:
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/19845/bottle.HTTPResponse

and return a HTTPResponse() object with a status and body:

```
 return HTTPResponse(
            status=400,
            body=json.dumps({'error': 'error adding new item'}))
```

Comment: This does not replace the message. If you try it with postman you will 400 Bad request...

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading the docs I found the solution.
Just replace the status code, i.e. 400 with a string like "400 Something went bad".

Just like that:

```
#before
response.status = 400

#after
response.status = "400 Something went bad"
```

And you're done.

See the doc: [THE RESPONSE OBJECT](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#the-response-object)